# Convert string to date format that can be used in a craft.entries tag

Tags: entries, datetime

I've got a date string from the url in this format: "2021-06-01" (year-month-day) and I want to find entries that have a date in the year and month from that string. The date is a date field in Craft.

```
{% set entries = entries.startsOn(craft.app.request.getParam('departure')|date("Y-m")) %}
```

That does not work!

Any ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
{# Your date 2020-11 in atom format e.g 2020-11-01T00:00:00+01:00 #}
{% set departureDate = craft.app.request.getParam('departure') | date("Y-m") | atom %}

{# Your date + 1 month in atom format e.g 2020-12-01T00:00:00+01:00 #}
{% set untilDate = departureDate | date_modify('+1 month') | atom %}

{# Query between those 2 dates #}
{% set query = query.startsOn(['and','>=' ~ departureDate, '<' ~  untilDate ]) %}
```

Note that on the November the 25th for example, you'd only be querying 5 days of the month

Comment: Hey @oli ah ok, that's cool, that is what I did in the end, but it felt like maybe i could have been able to do it the way I hoped!!

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the date string you get from your parametern without even editing it.

```php
{% set entries = entries.startsOn(craft.app.request.getParam('departure')) %}
```

More information about querying on datefields can be found here: [Date Fields | Craft CMS Documentation | 3.x](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/date-time-fields.html#templating)

Comment: I'm specifically looking to do just the year and month, not the day as well!

Comment: You could try to slice the date string to only display the year and month (`date|slice(0,7)`). I'm not sure if this would be a valid parameter. If not, you could try to use this as parameter: `['and', '>= date|slice(0,7)-01, '<= date|slice(0,7)-31']`